# Using javascript to make header buttons click thru

Tags: javascript

I created a child theme for my site, tdotargetmarketing.com. If you look, you’ll see the header has three buttons. I broke the header down to the table you see below. Slice 3, 5 and 7 are the buttons on the site that need to click thru. I created pages for those three buttons so I have the url/page. I added this table below in the editor section of the childtheme’s css file. Now, I think I need to add javascript code but this is where I’m stuck. Not sure of the proper sequence.

Don’t laugh, lol… I just finished the HTML/CSS/javascript basic course on Codecademy so I’m getting it but just not quite there. Can anyone help with this?

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
 <tr colspan="8">
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_01.jpg" width="1600" height="171">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_02.jpg" width="179" height="229">
  </td>
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_03.jpg" width="278" height="229">
  </td>
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_04.jpg" width="208" height="229">
  </td>
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_05.jpg" width="276" height="229">    
  </td>
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_06.jpg" width="203" height="229">
  </td>
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_07.jpg" width="278" height="229">
  </td>
  <td>
   <img src="Slice_08.jpg" width="179" height="229">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A tip for the future: Tables are intended to display information in a data table, not to the position HTML elements. CSS is better for that.

Comment: and you don't even have to compromise, since you can use CSS to cause other tags to be laid out like a table. divs 4 life.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript for this. Use an `a` tag to make hyperlinks in HTML.

```
<a href="url/page"><img src="Slice_03.jpg" width="278" height="229"></a>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Example.3A_Creating_a_clickable_image

unless I read the question wrong lol